# How would you say someone was "disrespecting you" correctly?

Tags: meaning, grammar

Is there a grammatically correct synonym for the word "disrespect" in the form of a verb? As in: "Please stop disrespecting me, Bill."

Comment: "Disrespect" can indeed be used as a transitive verb.

Comment: You could actually just be specific about what he is doing.

Comment: Don't diss me, Bill, or I'll give you the beat-down.

Comment: You don't "tell someone" not to disrespect you. It's just not done.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany :) "Why you be dissin' me?" http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=diss

Comment: Try this: "All I'm asking is for a little respect.  Just a little bit.  Hey baby, just a little bit.  Sock it to me, sock it to me..."

Comment: Thanks everyone! I just wanted to know what was the correct verb form of "disrespect". I didn't realize that "disrespect" as verb was correct.

Answer (score 3):

If you are unhappy with that construction you can say:

> Please stop showing me disrespect Bill.

But, [disrespecting](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disrespect) me is perfectly acceptable.  It is a transitive verb as Jez points out in comments above.

Answer (score 1):

"Please stop being disrespectful to me, Bill" can work also.

Answer (score 0):

The verb *to disrespect* is, at least to my ear, colloquial.  I'd say something along the following lines, especially in an academic or professional setting: Bill, show me the respect I've earned.  Bill, show me the respect I deserve.  Bill, could you show me some respect here.
This approach also solves the problem of the logical double negative, which is a less-powerful expression.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on circumstances, environment and level of rapport a simple "Fuck  off!" might do. If you don't know that person or need to be respectful yourself then [a thesaurus gives us a few more polite synonyms for disrespect.](http://thesaurus.com/browse/disrespect)

There we have:

(And these are just example sentences)

1. You are being very bold today, aren't you?
2. Your impertinence is beyond good and bad right now. Wanna talk about it?
3. Incivility, where did you learn it?
4. Your insolence cannot be tolerated any longer, stop it right now. Or else!
5. Where are your manners my mate? Are you having a bad day?
6. As a courtesy to you I'm gonna be pointing out to you your discourtesy. What is the reason for your incivility (towards me)?

Comment: You have some actual answers mixed in among the garbage.  Please edit the beginning.  I think that both the giant/bold print and fake swear words are responsible for the down vote you received.  If you want to write fuck off, then write fuck off.  But, I don't think it is the answer the OP was asking for.

Comment: Thx for the feedback @DavidM. Done, where is my up vote. ;)

Comment: If you want to attract disrespect, swearing at someone is a good way to do it.

Comment: @BenMiller Also not swearing at someone is also a good way to do it. The key to being respected is self respect. Anything else follows and is just icing on the cake.